# Catching a signal in linux

Tags: linux, signals

I am working on Linux.
I wrote a function that is called when an SIGSEGV is sent.

I check my program by sending from command prompt `kill -SIGSEGV pid`.
I remark that when my program is not polling for new ethernet input, it doesn't catch the signal and enter 'zombie state' i.e. it doesn't write nothing to log file...

Is there a logic explanation why program doesn't ***always*** catch  signals ?

Comment: SIGSEGV is a signal. You mix the terms signal and interrupt.

Comment: 1. get your terms straight, SIGSEVG is a *signal* - interrupts are a completely different animal and rarely have anything to do with userspace programs. 2. I'm sure there is a logical explanation, but you caught us at a bad time - we all left our crystal balls at home and we can't see your code without them.

Comment: I can't post code (thousand of files...). This why i asked for a logic explanation.

Comment: Does your program have multiple threads?  If so the signal may be delivered to any of them that do not have the signal blocked.

Comment: No it is a single thread process

Comment: You need to reduce the size of the code showing the problem. By the way, 'zombie' as a very precise meaning when it comes to process stat. Is there actually a Z in ps output for this process ?

Comment: So what happens when it doesn't catch the signal?  Does the program continue running or exit or crash?  Try running the program under strace and then under gdb to track down what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one thread that will only "listen" for SIGSEVG signal and another one that will only poll for new internet input.

This way your program won't "miss" SIGSEVG signal while polling for new ethernet input.

Comment: Signals, especialy SIGSEGV, is not something a program can just ignore, regardless of what it is doing at the time...

Comment: @thkala In this way, the polling work can be delegated to a thread while the main program will only focus on its other activities and SIGSEVG handling.

Comment: @DavidBobo I can't say, I was just giving you in the answer a general rule employed in application dealing with the network activity. Usually, the network is devoted to a thread. The main program can then focus its other tasks.